# How to call a function in C code with Struct as parameter from C#

Tags: c#, c, marshalling

I have a struct in C file as shown below

```
struct Parameter{
    char param1[20];
    char param2[20];
}
```

and also a function in C file which takes this struct as parameter along with char* as another parameter as shown below

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetValue(char* opt,struct Parameter param);
void GetValue(char* opt, struct Parameter params)
{
printf("%s", params->param1);
}
```

I want to call it from my C# application using marshalling. I have created a similar struct in C#

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public class Parameters
{      
    public string Param1 { get; set; }     
    public string Param1 { get; set; }   
}
```

and calling it in C# using the below method

```
 [DllImport(@"C:\Test\CTestDll.dll",CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl,CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]      
 public static extern void GetValue([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]StringBuilder sbOut, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]Parameters sbIn);
```

but the result which is a print statement is printing null.I am not very good in C programming. Kindly help me to sort it out. Where I am wrong, Is it in the C function or marshalling from C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that in C++ your structure contains raw chars, while in C# you class contains reference to string. MarshalAs attribute will use a char array instead of a reference to string:

```
unsafe static class Program
{

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Parameters
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
    public String Param1;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
    public String Param2;
}


[DllImport(@"CTestDll2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern void GetValue(StringBuilder sbOut, Parameters sbIn);


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = new Parameters
    {
        Param1 = "abc",
        Param2 = "dfc"
    };

    var s = new StringBuilder("some text");

    GetValue(s, p);
}
```

}

C++:

```
// CTestDll.h

#pragma once

#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void GetValue(char* opt, struct Parameter param);

struct Parameter{
    char param1[20];
    char param2[20];
};

void GetValue(char* opt, struct Parameter params)
{
    printf("param1: %s, param2: %s, string: %s", params.param1, params.param2, opt);
}
```

Comment: Updated w/ more preferable solution.

Comment: Your text still says "use char array".

Comment: @RamanZhylich- Thanks a lot for reply. But after trying you solution I got this exception in my C3 application where I am calling the marshelled function --   Cannot marshal 'parameter #2': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (this value type must be paired with Struct).

Comment: You should use struct instead of class

Comment: Also try to pass it as a ref paramter, i.e public static extern void GetValue([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]StringBuilder sbOut, ref Parameters sbIn);

Comment: @RamanZhylich - I tried using the ref , the exception is gone but I am now at at orginal doubt, I am getting Null value as op in C function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13849/discussion-between-vikram-and-raman-zhylich)

Comment: You mean first parameter string is null? What about struct, was it passed properly?

Comment: Vikram, I've created Win32 DLL in C++ and tested everything. Please, see updated code. It works on my box.

Comment: @RamanZhylich - waaw its great. it's working at personal laptop.. i will try it out in offc and give it a try. Thanks a lot for the great help.